# Passport local protect sub-pages if user didn't login

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I follow this [tutorial](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/01/31/local-authentication-with-passport-and-express-4/#comment-2823871815) but has trouble 'protecting' my pages if the user did not login. I want to redirect them to login page.

I've tried to do a middleware in app.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.user){
      return res.redirect('/login_');
    }
    next();
  }
})
```

but I got an infinite loop.

[image]

Comment: Hi, you are getting loop because on `/login_` your auth middleware works too, so you need to check if page is not `/login_` and `!res.user` then redirect to `/login_`

Answer (score 0):

It's because your middleware is being set on all the routes, not just your protected routes. You don't want your login route to be protected.

Set your middleware to check for login on a router that groups all your protected routes. Here's a [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4) on how to do it.